# NGINX redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, nginx

I try to redirect HTTPS request to HTTP using NGINX.

This how I edited

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

on my VPS:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  exapmle.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/laravel/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        if ( $https = "on" ) {
                return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

So any ideas what i have done wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to redirect https to http?

Comment: I try to run google ads and they do not accept my ads because of this: https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6368661?hl=en&authuser=0#673

Comment: @Difster in my ads they say: Destination not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen on port 443 (HTTPS) and redirect to HTTP. You don't have anything showing that you're listening on 443.

Try this instead:

```
server {
listen       443;
server_name  exapmle.com;
rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
```

}

Comment: 'server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}' is it have to look like this?

Comment: That looks about right. Test it out and see how it works.

Comment: That should work in general, perhaps you'rd approaching the problem from the wrong angle. Are you saying this doesn't work with your ads, or it doesn't work with anything? Let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150558/discussion-between-dmitry-malys-and-difster).